# Java: Generic JAXB Serialization

Tags: java, generics, serialization, jaxb

I'm looking for a generic way to serialize objects in Java using JAXB XML Serialization.  I'd like to have something like this:

```
public static <T> String serializeUsingJAXB(T entity) {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(T.class);
    // ...
}
```

However, it looks as though due to type erasure, `T.class` doesn't work.

What will?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `entity.getClass()`

Comment: @Jason: Make sure that in your requirements `entity` is never `null`.  If it ever is, you'll get NPE.

Comment: Yes, I will certainly do that.  Thanks.

Comment: You could also use the JAXB class and save a line or two of code see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549334/java-generic-jaxb-serialization/3549916#3549916

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> String serializeUsingJAXB(
    T entity,
    Class< ? extends T> clazz
)
{
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( clazz );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @Tom. It could, but I have no clue what's the rest of this method looks like.  This is pretty generic Generics programming technique.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the rest of the method is.

Answer (score 1):

You might also consider:

```
public static <T> String serializeUsingJAXB(T entity) { 
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    javax.xml.bind.JAXB.marshal(entity, writer);
    return writer.toString();
}
```

For more information see the [javax.xml.bind.JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html) class

Comment: Thanks for that, it's good to know. I don't mind doing it the long way since I can set the JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT property of the Marshaller to false.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is:

```
public static String serializeUsingJAXB(Object entity, JAXBContext context) {
    // ...
}
```